# Javascript works inline but not in a file

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am assuming that the answer is simple and right under my nose, but I can't seem to find the proverbial dog that's going to bite me.

Anyway, this works inline:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function foo(){

    alert("BOO!")

    }
</script>

<body onload=foo()>...
```

But if I do:

```
<script type="text\javascript" scr="js/blah.js">
</script>

<body onload=foo()>
```

blah.js contains:

```
function foo(){

    alert("BOO!")

    }
```

That doesn't work.

Why?

Comment: Did you check the path to the file is correct?

Comment: check in firebug whether the file is getting loaded properly or not..

Comment: It works for me.. check the path of the blah.js and if it does get loaded....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
<body onload="foo();">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But still I get this error:Unknown thread
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: foo
Error thrown at line 1, column 0 in <anonymous function>(event) in file://localhost/X:/COMPUTERS/Programming/WEBDEV/WEBSITE/foo.com/index.html:
    foo();

Comment: @MattMatt looks like it has not been declared before. That probably means that the file could not be located. Did you correct the errors that were pointed out on the comments?

Answer (score 2):

The type is `text/javascript` (`/` instead of `\`), and the onload attribute in the body element should be `onload="foo();"`.

Also, is your blah.js file stored inside a directory called js?

Comment: and he misspelled "src" as "scr"

Comment: @Paul Good catch. That's probably the reason why is not loading the js. Mine would be most likely overlooked by the browser (except the file not being in the specified directory possibility).

Comment: Yup... that was it.  I just caught that. *insert facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Inside markup you can call JavaScript functions. There is nothing wrong with it. This creates a new anonymous function in the `DOM` tree and adds the value of the Event model as the function body.

```
<script type="text\javascript" scr="js/blah.js"> </script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/blah.js"> </script> // / and src
```

should be

```
<body onload="foo()"> // Markup attribute values should be passed inside quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

All attribute values has to begin with " and end with "